# Scrapy crawler function not executing

Tags: python, scrapy

New to Python and crawling, for some reason the below code is not executing the function when its called, it doesn't even output the "test" print statement.

The main parse executes fine its just the call to the function, i have  tried many different ways of calling it to no avail.

```
import scrapy
from myproject.items import MyHierarchyItem

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myspider"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = ['example.com']

    def parse(self, response):

        print("Starting parse_hierarchy")
        HierarchyItem = MyHierarchyItem() 
        StartLvl3URLS = []
        sitemap = response.css("div.sitemap-content > div.row")

        for lvl1 in sitemap:            
            HierarchyItem["hierarchy_lvl1_name"] = lvl1.css("h2::text").extract()
            #print(lvl1.css("h2::text").extract())
            currentlvl2 = lvl1.css("li.span-6")

            for lvl2 in currentlvl2:
                HierarchyItem["hierarchy_lvl2_name"] = lvl2.css("h4::text").extract()
                currentlvl3 = lvl2.css("ul.child > li")
                #print(lvl2.css("h4::text").extract())

                for lvl3 in currentlvl3:
                    #print(lvl3.css("a::text").extract())
                    #print(lvl3.css("a::attr(href)").extract())
                    HierarchyItem["hierarchy_lvl3_name"] = lvl3.css("a::text").extract()
                    HierarchyItem["hierarchy_url"] = lvl3.css("a::attr(href)").extract()
                    StartLvl3URLS.append(HierarchyItem["hierarchy_url"])
                    yield HierarchyItem

        full_link = StartLvl3URLS[0]
        #for lvl3 in StartLvl3URLS
        yield scrapy.Request(str(full_link), self.parse_category)

    def parse_category(self, response):
        print("test")
        print(len(reponse.body))
        print(response.body)
```

Log extract

```
2017-04-08 23:58:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.example.com/sitemap>
{'hierarchy_lvl1_name': ['cat1'],
 'hierarchy_lvl2_name': ['cat2'],
 'hierarchy_lvl3_name': ['cat3'],
 'hierarchy_url': ['http://www.example.com/cat1/cat2/cat3']}
2017-04-08 23:58:03 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-04-08 23:58:03 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored csv feed (445 items) in: hierarchy.csv
2017-04-08 23:58:03 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 205,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 24223,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 8, 13, 58, 3, 154254),
 'httpcache/hit': 1,
 'item_scraped_count': 445,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 447,
 'log_count/INFO': 8,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 8, 13, 58, 2, 614750)}
2017-04-08 23:58:03 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, the problem was that because i was using `extract()` its output is a list, so i had a list within a list ( with only one element ) and the request wasn't calling the url, changed it to a `extract_first()` and now it works.

```
HierarchyItem["hierarchy_url"] = lvl3.css("a::attr(href)").extract_first()
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy does not prints output printing via `print()` method as per my knowledge.

You can do

```
import logging
logging.info("message here")
logging.error("message here")
logging.warning("message here")
```

Also disable JavaScript in browser and open the website you are scraping. and then check if `div.sitemap-content > div.row` selector returns any element or not.